# On determining a video source's position by evaluating it's video stream

Tags: c#-4.0, kinect, kinect-sdk, ransac

What are the steps to

a) get a kinect's position by evaluating it's sensor data(ie depth stream, video stream, audio stream)

b) get a regular camera's position by evaluating it's sensor data(ie video stream)

Comment: I wouldn't have asked otherwise.  The use of "position" is vague and does not convey exactly what you want to be finding.  Provide an example use case of what you trying to accomplish.

Comment: Now this sounds better. Goal is to use kinect/camera as an inverse headtracker. You mount it on your hmd and by detecting how the surrounding moves you determine pitch, yaw, roll and position in space.

Comment: As you have all information now I demand a reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the accelerometer data could help you. Look at this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GWvcgZkADUU